# Laravel PHP: Controller not being updated

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to make some changes in one of my controllers but after I save the file, the changes do not take effect and variables are not recognized.  I've added some more files to my controller so I'm not really sure if it's a namespace issue or if using 'composer dump-autoload' had an effect on it.

**OverviewController.php (Controller):**

```
 <?php 

 use controllers\VideosController;

 use app\models\Video;

 use Acme\repositories\VideoRepository;

 /* Added the 3 'Picture' files below */   

 use controllers\PicturesController;

 use app\models\Picture;

 use Acme\repositories\PictureRepository;

 use models\Validators as Validators;

 class OverviewController extends BaseController {

  /* 
  The Video model for the repository
  */
  protected $video;

  /* 
  The Picture model for the repository
  */
  protected $picture;

  /* The layout for the Videos and Pictures Overview */
  protected $layout = 'layouts.master';


 public function __construct(VideoRepository $video)
 {
    $this->video = $video;
 }

/* Added this repository function as well. */

 public function __construct(PictureRepository $picture)
 {
    $this->picture = $picture;
 }

 /* List all the videos and stones
 Included Pagination for neatness */

 public function index()
 {
    $allpicsvids = Video::paginate(10);

    /* Added this variable to this function and it is not being recognized */
    $allpics = Picture::paginate(10);


    $this->layout->content = \View::make('home.pics_vids_overview', array('allpicsvids' => $allpicsvids, 'allpics' =>$allpics));
 }


}
```

I don't know why the additions to this controller are not being recognized after I save it.  I've tried running 'php artisan dump-autoload' and 'composer dump-autoload' but I'm still not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: I get an error message within the view in that the variable 'allpics' is not recognized.  I've actually tried commenting out the entire 'index()' block of code, removed 'allpics' from the view and it still runs.  In other words, it is running the original version of 'OverviewController.php' and not the updated version.

Comment: Hmm usually controllers don't get cached, but views are. I don't know if this helps, but you could try to delete all the files in the `app/storage/views` folder

Comment: Tried that, still no effect.  The controller is still not updated.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is now.  I ran 'composer dump-autoload' and I think that had an effect on all of my files since none of the controllers are being updated.  I'm going to try to re-create my project in another directory and hopefully things will work out.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled for a couple of hours on this until I realized I was passing the variables to the index.blade.php, but inside of it I was using a partial and forgot to pass the vars again from the index.blade.php to the partial.

So, basically, you have to manually propagate the vars like this Controller->View->Partials.

Comment: I also recently discovered that it is more practical to share a single object to the all the blades rather than passing an array of vars, that way if you add new data to the object as properties, you don't need to update your view:make(s) inside of the blades when calling other blades, you just use the property when you need it after you add more data to the object.